# How to switch between EJB2.x to EJB3.x dynamically?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

I have got an application which has EJB2.x and EJB3.x version of ejb.
Business logic for both EJBs is same.

I need to implement ability to switch dynamically between the two EJBs on basis of JNDI.
I would be using local interface of EJB3.x and  Home interface for 2.x.
This would not be a issue if EJBs were of same type (like all were 2.x or all were 3.x). But can't figure out how to achieve this with different types of EJBs?

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions of your problem.

1. Write proxy class, which encapsulate work with older and newer version of beans and can choose version by changing of some parameter of this proxy class.
2. Implement [OSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)